# laravel- many to many relationship with tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**it is my article model**

```
function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**it is my article model**

```
function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

---

**it is my article controllers store method**

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request, Article $article)   
{
    $article=Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());

    $article->tags()->attach($request->input('tags'));

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

**i had this error**

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()

help me resolve this

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `$article` is? Try using `dd($article);` after loading it in your controller.

Comment: Could you post the `routes` file please?

Answer (score 0):

if I try the **dd($articles)**, I had this out put

```
                        Article {#206 ▼
                        #fillable: array:3 [▶]
                        #connection: null
                        #table: null
                        #primaryKey: "id"
                        #perPage: 15
                        +incrementing: true
                        +timestamps: true
                        #attributes: array:7 [▶]
                        #original: array:7 [▶]
                        #relations: []
                        #hidden: []
                        #visible: []
                        #appends: []
                        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
                        #dates: []
                        #dateFormat: null
                        #casts: []
                        #touches: []
                        #observables: []
                        #with: []
                        #morphClass: null
                        +exists: true
                        +wasRecentlyCreated: true
                       }
```

**And The routes file is:**

```
                  <?php

                   Route::get('/', function () {
                   return view('welcome');
                    });


                   Route::resource('articles','articlescontroller');

                   Route::controllers([
                          'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
                          'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
                            ]);
```